# CosmosDb using mongoose( Collection name )

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, mongoose-schema

i have the schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var BookSchema = new Schema({
    title:{
        type:String,
        require:true,
        index: true,
        unique:true
    },
    author:String,
    category:String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', BookSchema);
```

What should my collection name in CosmosDb be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you defined in the schecma, a new collection named **`Book`** will be created in cosmosdb